# X-Men movies discrepancies

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

I'm an avid watcher and lover of the X-Men movies. The original trilogy, the X-men wolverine series, as well *X-Men: First Class* and *DoFP*.

With *X-Men: The Last Stand*, Mystique has lost her powers, Professor X has died, and the closing scene shows Magneto having a hint of his power left.

The next time we actually meet Professor X or Magneto is in *Days of Future Past*. (Unless I'm mistaken) and this is where my confusion lies.

Is there a story behind how Professor X is still alive, or what has happened over the past years?

Is each subsequent film only lightly based upon the previous?
Or are they going to continue to try and fill in the gaps non-chronologically?

Comment: We see both Professor X and Magneto briefly after the closing credits of *The Wolverine*, where they attempt to recruit Wolverine for a mission --- implied to be the mission of *Days of Future Past*, but even this doesn't connect well with the timeline in *DoFP*.